# How much checking should one do? - (simple jQuery Log function sparks philosophical debates)

Tags: logging

I created a simple a jQuery function that is to be used for developer event and error logging... it calls a web service function that simply logs several passed parameters to a log table called *EventLog*.

One of the parameters (*logEventStr*) is just a string that qualifies the log event... like 'debug', 'error', 'user', 'info'... et cetera. I have all of these event types in another table, call it *EventTypes*, indexed (i.e. 1=debug, 2=info, 3=user...), and linked via foreign key constraint to an eventId column the log table.

So, during a code review it was suggested/argued that some initial checking on this log event string should be used since "a developer could possibly mistype the event type in the *logEventStr* parameter". I explained that I have code in the web service that checks for a valid event string and throws an exception that is handled in the failure event of the Ajax call... it even prints out the misspelled event name error to the console, so the developer would immediately know that he messed up and would correct it. Further 'discussions' stated that the indexes in *EventTypes* should be hard-coded (probably a JSON object) in the javascript and checked before making the web service call. This just seemed silly to me, as now the developers will have to keep up with changes in the *EventTypes* table and keep them manually synced with the hard-coded JSON object. I finally relented somewhat to populating the JSON object with yet another web service call that returns the contents of the EventTypes table and caches it so it would be a one-time call on first hit. I still think, however, that even this is unnecessary... the logging function is only to be used by the developer and the *logEventStr* will never be dictated by an end-user.

My question is... which technique is right? How much checking should be required for something as straight-forward and simple as a logging function, that is to be used exclusively by the developers?

I've mulled this about over the weekend and it still bothers me. Of course, maybe neither of these is the correct approach, so alternative ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a wrapper function for every log event type?

If your original function is `log`, and is used like this:

```
log("user", "is a zombie");
```

this could be rewritten as:

```
logUser("is a zombie");
```

where `logUser` simply calls `log` with the parameter `user`.

Another route to go would be to make `log` an object with various functions, so you would use it like this:

```
log.user("is a zombie");
```

etc.

The developers using your logging mechanism shouldn't be bothered with its internals, and since we're dealing with a logging system here, there is a finite amount of logging types, so if you put upfront a well thought out list of logging types that exist in the database and won't need to be modified, then there shouldn't be worries of something breaking in the future.

**Edit** (based on comment):

From your question, I see there are two tables, `EventLog` and `EventTypes`. I presume `EventLog` has two columns:

- eventId
- event,

while `EventTypes` also has two columns:

- eventId
- eventDescription.

This bit of information puzzles me, and I quote:

> now the developers will have to keep
>   up with changes in the EventLog table

From my understanding, the purpose of this table is to store information about various events and their types. This table will change in sense that rows will be added every time an event is logged. No structural changes here.

The `EventTypes` table is the one that could change, and also in a way that new event types are added. This also means a row may be added.

Both tables won't be modified in a way that their columns will be added or removed.

`EventTypes` is more or less "fixed", and every event type is associated to a number. This number should be an "agreement" between your database and your Javascript.

So, if you have three rows like this:

- 1 | debug
- 2 | info
- 3 | user

then you should also have three functions like this:

- log.debug
- log.info
- log.user

and each one should call your webservice with appropriate number. This is your agreement.

If a new event type is added, so now your table has a new row like this:

- 4 | error

then you should add a new function for your developers:

- log.error

This way, there are no "breaking changes", since new functionality is added and nothing old is broken in the process. Assuming your numbering scheme doesn't change.

You just tell your developers "you've got a new function from now on, everything else will work like it did before" and you go ahead with your business.

Comment: Hmm... kind of liking this idea (log.user). Even better since those internal event types will infrequently change, and takes care of the "misspelling" potential. What would be your thoughts on the philosophical aspects of this discussion?

Comment: I see you get the jist of my awkward question, and yes I meant "developers will have to keep up with EventTypes", not EventLog. Your addendum makes even more sense now because adding a function is equivalent to adding another event type, as it should. I like this better because it solves my problem of having to keep up with the lists in two areas - namely the client side and the DB side.